# How to render `React Component` not to the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Lets say I want to render React component on the fly and got the real DOM element for future use

for example, if I have that component :

```
 function Card({symbol,id,color}){
  return <my-card symbol={} id={} color={color}></my-card>
 }
```

how can I render it and got the element ?

maybe like that

```
 const cardElement = React.render(<Card symbol='4' id=111 color='♥'/>)
```

I need real element for play around with it. do some measurements. and then delete it.

But I think that it's common need from framework to have some way to let a developer hold real DOM element if it need it; I mean, good framework should have a way to do that

Comment: Might be better to describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use something like this:

```
const preRender = () => <Card symbol='4' id=111 color='♥'/>
```

Now you have the content of `Card` stateless component, rendered in `preRender` variable

Comment: what you are offer just return what you say. `preRender` variable . but I need real element for play around with it. do some measurements. and then delete it

Answer (score 0):

`render` returns component instance and not DOM. As `ReactDOM.render` [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) states,

> Render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container and
>   return a reference to the component (or returns null for stateless
>   components).
>
> If the React element was previously rendered into container, this will
>   perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to
>   reflect the latest React element.
>
> If the optional callback is provided, it will be executed after the
>   component is rendered or updated.

DOM is rendered to provided container element:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(<Card ... />, element);
console.log(element.outerHTML);
```

If a component is asynchronous, a callback should be used to retrieve asynchronous updates to DOM.

Comment: thank .  so you offer to render the component to empty `div`?

Comment: I don't certainly offer that because this could be XY problem that has to be solved in another way. This depends on your needs. There's already a comment that suggests to update the question with details that explain your problem.